# How to modify the Eclipse Run Configuration classpath for an OSGi application?

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi

At Eclipse Run/Debug Configurations there is a 'Classpath' tab when it is
a 'Java Application' configuration, but when it is an 'OSGi Framework' it doesn't.
How can I set the classpath for an OSGi application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found it by myself.

Settings tab > Bootstrap entries

From: [Eclipse documentation](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/launchers/equinox_settings.htm?cp=4_3_3_1_2)

> Bootstrap Entries
>
> By default, the only entry on the launch configuration classpath is
>   the ${target_home}/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher JAR. The
>   ${target_home}/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher JAR file houses
>   the org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main class which contains the
>   bootstrap code. The ${target_home} variable refers to the location of
>   the target platform as specified on the Window > Preferences... >
>   Plug-in Development > Target Platform preference page.
>
> The Bootstrap Entries field allows you to specify and append
>   additional locations to the classpath, if required.